# Storing value of checkbox that lies inside custom ListView.

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, listview-adapter

i am trying to get the selected value of checkbox and store it in database.. i am able to click on checkbox inside the ListView. But i am getting NullPointer Exception due to this line of code
" subjects.setSelected(cb.isChecked()); "
help!!

i am following this tutorial by the way!
http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html?showComment=1397151611795#c1803690674156959933

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserRecordHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);            
        holder = new UserRecordHolder();
        holder.txtName=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ttvSubjectNamePSS);
        holder.txtCode=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ttvSubjectCodePSS);
        holder.cbSubj=(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cbPSS);

        row.setTag(holder);
        holder.cbSubj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 
                SbjData subjects = (SbjData) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "clicked on : "+ cb.getText() +"is "+cb.isChecked(), 2).show(); 
                //This line shows exception                            
                subjects.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), 5).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
    else
    {
        holder = (UserRecordHolder)row.getTag();
    }


public class SbjData { 
  public String sbj_name,sbj_code,sbj_depId,sbj_crcId; 
  public int sbj_id; 
  boolean selected = false; 
  public SbjData() { 
     super(); 
  } 
  public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
     this.selected = selected; 
  } 
  public boolean isSelected() {
     return selected; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: cb.getTag() is null. What is SbjData?

Comment: SbjData is class as follows

Comment: public class SbjData 
{
 public String sbj_name,sbj_code,sbj_depId,sbj_crcId;
 public int sbj_id;
 boolean selected = false;
 
 public SbjData()
 {
  super();
 }
 public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
   }
 public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
   }

}

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the tutorial at line #130: `holder.name.setTag(country);`

You don't have something like this in your code